# Why isn't EvaluatorFilter filtering non-matching statements?

Tags: java, logback

We are using TomEE, SLF4J and Logback. Our aim is to log certain logging statements into a database (determined by a marker), in addition to the stdout. Here is our logback configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>...</encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="DB" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
        <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
            <driverClass>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driverClass>
            <url>...</url>
        </connectionSource>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
            <evaluator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.OnMarkerEvaluator">
                <marker>LOGDATABASE</marker>
            </evaluator>
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="DB" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

But although the marker isn't set, the DBAppender logs to the database. Why?

Answer (score 2):

The filter wasn't working as expected, because I didn't set the "onMatch" and "onMismatch" tags. Here's the working solution:

```
<filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
    <evaluator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.OnMarkerEvaluator">
        <marker>LOGDATABASE</marker>
    </evaluator>
    <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
    <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
</filter>
```